# How can I run a python program in the background using python's Command Line Scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have my program set up to run with Command Line Scripts (https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) like so:

```
 "console_scripts": ["app_name = app_name.app:main"],
```

How can I make it so that this program runs in the background like pythonw does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `console_scripts`, something that should be run as a GUI application goes in `gui_scripts`.

```
 "console_scripts": ["app_name = app_name.cli:command_line"],
 "gui_scripts": ["app_name = app_name.gui:start_window"],
```

See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/

Comment: Found this a few minutes ago as well. This did the trick however, I need to also have an interactive session when requested or by default. That's for another question though. Thanks.